# Proving upper/lower bound

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, correctness-proof

> $f (n) = Θ(f (n/2))$

The counter example in the solutions was $f(n)=\sqrt{n}$.

But then we get for every $n\ge n_{0}$

$\sqrt{n}\le c_{0}\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\ \ ->\ \ n\le c_{0}^{2}\cdot\frac{n}{2}\ \ \ ->\ \ 2n\le c_{0}^{2}\cdot n\ \ ->\ 2\le c_{0}^{2}$

and I don't see a problem with that, as we can choose $c_{0}=2$. Same with the omega definition. So what am I missing?

Comment: In your reasonings you missed nothing, of course $\sqrt{n}\in \Theta(\sqrt{n/2})=\Theta(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably a mistake in their solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counter-example isn't true.

Let $f(n)=2^n$, we see that
$$f(\frac{n}{2})=2^\frac{n}{2}=\sqrt{2}^n.$$

As a result we show that $f(n)\neq\Theta(f(\frac{n}{2}))$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{f(\frac{n}{2})}=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{2}^n}$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\times\dots\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}\times\dots\times\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2}^n}{1}=\infty.$$
So, $f(n)\neq\Theta(f(\frac{n}{2}))$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't thought about making n a power of something. :)